in dplyr summarize() add a column listing what is summarized across
In using dplyr::summarize() I'm trying to both create a single row for a single variable and also create a variable that, rather than summing numeric values in another variable, has a string that includes the text from each observation in that column. In other words, I want to turn this:

df <- data.frame(v1 = c('X','X','Y','Z'), v2 = c('A','B','A','A'))

  v1 v2
1  X  A
2  X  B
3  Y  A
4  Z  A

into this:
  v1  v3
1  X A,B
2  Y   A
3  Z   A

my first thought was summarize(v3 = paste(v2)) but that doesn't really produce anything. Is there a way to do this?

This is exactly the thing. Thank you! Wording this the right way in search was difficult.
